# make phone call on keeping touch an string

Tags: android, onclick, android-adapter, android-gridview

I have a problem that dont know how to search,its a difficult search.
I have a simple GridView with 3 column,firs columns named name,second named phoneNumber, and last named status.
the second column is phone numbers that i want to show all in one ArrayList. (All in string)
It shows it ok,
But i want when user keep touch on second column , or click it, or anything, the android dialog apperas that call this phone number.
how can i do this?

what i search about this, shows about calling methods and classes.

My simple Code here :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, arrayList);

    ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
    CallableStatement callableStatement;

    try {
        callableStatement =  connectionHelper.getConnection().prepareCall("{call getData}");
        callableStatement.execute();
        ResultSet resultSet =  callableStatement.getResultSet();
        if(resultSet.next())
        {
            String name ;
            int p;
            String status;
            String phone;
            name = resultSet.getString("Name"); // get name from SP
            p = resultSet.getInt("PhoneNumber"); // get the int of phoneNumber
            status = resultSet.getString("Status");
            phone = String.valueOf(p); // cast integer to string
            arrayList.add(name);
            arrayList.add(phone);
            arrayList.add(status);
            arrayAdapter.getItemViewType(R.id.gridView);
            gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to add a OnItemClickListener to your Grid View. This will enable the on click event when grid item is clicked/touched on your app.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
  //Your Working will be done here.
}
});
```

Now You say that your phone number is in second postition, so add this :-

So,

```
if(position == 1)
{
Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_CALL );          
phoneCallIntent.setData( Uri.parse( "tel:" + phone ) );          
startActivity( phoneCallIntent );
}
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: I Used your code,The Intent part, as Below.
In a Button clickListener.

  callNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + arrayList.get(gridView.getCheckedItemPosition()).toString()));
                            startActivity(callIntent);
});

Comment: I think that should solve your provided you gave permission in manifest file.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an "intent" to make the phone call:

```
Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_CALL );          
phoneCallIntent.setData( Uri.parse( "tel:" + phone ) );          
startActivity( phoneCallIntent );
```

You can then put that code into an onClick event for the column.

For more information you can search for something like: "android intent phone call"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the click event only on the 2nd column. To do that you need to set the click listener on your grid view and then check the position.
Try something like below code.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            if(position%3 ==1){
                try {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"your mobile no"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "There are no calling clients installed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

    }
});
```